# How do COVID-19 Vaccination ID verifications work? How do they ensure that the ID is not faked?

Tags: algorithms

How do COVID-19 Vaccination ID verifications work? How do they automatically verify that the COVID-19 Vaccination ID is not faked?

Comment: You need to give more details about your scenario. What type of ID? What verification? Make sure that your question is [on-topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for cs.stackexchange.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  It's an interesting topic, but I suspect this may be too broad to be a good fit here.  There are many systems out there for vaccination ID, and they don't all work the same way.

Comment: My guess is that there is a database they are querying, and verifying your identity using your personal ID. But again, this may change from country to country...

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult, and it's more suitable for a security website.

Usually you get a QR code. A QR code can be cryptographically signed, and if it is signed, it cannot practically be forged. So you can't create a QR code that shows you are vaccinated.

But I can make a copy of your QR code. That QR code would then prove that someone with your name, possibly your face, and possibly your passport number, is vaccinated. If I tried to get on a flight with that QR code, someone would check and see that the QR code proves *you* are vaccinated, but it doesn't prove that *I* am vaccinated, because my photo and passport number don't match.

This is all based on some data in some government computer, and that data can be forged. There are currently three people in the UK in court for entering non-existing vaccinations into the system for money.